# Corda - Decoding Base58 public keys doesn't work

Tags: bouncycastle, corda, public-key

Decoding Base58 public keys back into `PublicKey` instances doesn't seem to work:

```
parsePublicKeyBase58("DLG9nscvKPbgagoLP7jr4oc5FygazKr7pdADZMGFizmpV8")
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: unknown tag 9 encountered
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at net.corda.core.crypto.Crypto.decodePublicKey(Crypto.kt:343)
>       at net.corda.core.utilities.EncodingUtils.parsePublicKeyBase58(EncodingUtils.kt:81)
>       at test.Program$Companion.main(Program.kt:15)
>       at test.Program.main(Program.kt)

What's wrong here?

**What error are you getting with that – Sneha Damle?**

```
parsePublicKeyBase58("G9nscvKPbgagoLP7jr4oc5FygazKr7pdADZMGFizmpV8")
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DEF length 31 object truncated by 1
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at net.corda.core.crypto.Crypto.decodePublicKey(Crypto.kt:343)
>       at net.corda.core.utilities.EncodingUtils.parsePublicKeyBase58(EncodingUtils.kt:81)
>       at test.ProgramKt.main(Program.kt:6)

Comment: Can you drop the “DL” prefix before parsing and try again?

Comment: @SnehaDamle I tried that too. Different error but it still didn't work.

Comment: what error are you getting with that

Comment: @SnehaDamle see update.

Comment: What is `parsePublicKeyBase58`? Is this an elliptic curve public key? Where is the key encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using an incorrect Base58 string. I did the following and it worked.

Encoded a Public Key to Base58

```
Base58.encode(party.getOwningKey().getEncoded()).toString();
```

This gave me the String `GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgyH7WThpV3Qn7zdCm4cKw8J5x8kVGnVkGtgAmh3KKE7EN4`

Decoded it:

```
PublicKey publicKey = EncodingUtils.parsePublicKeyBase58("GfHq2tTVk9z4eXgyH7WThpV3Qn7zdCm4cKw8J5x8kVGnVkGtgAmh3KKE7EN4");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If that's the case, what's the point of outputting a public key string that you can't do anything with?

Comment: Note - those keys are the result of calling `AnonymousParty.toString()`

Comment: The toString() method return a string of a SHA256 representation, I m not sure whats the purpose of that. I also found we have a method in EncodingUtils.toBase58String() which you could use to conveniently convert a public key to its base58 representation.